# How to handle external applications in a selenium-test?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a test that verifies that a warning to the user before the user opens a document. If the user says that they still would like to open the document, the document opens in an external application (pdf or word).

But now I have an external application over the browser window, and it messes up for other tests.

So, what are the best practices around this kind of issue? Rewrite of the appliction to allow for not opening documents in test?

Added description:
The problem is twofold. 
1) It starts processes (word and acrobat) that fills the desctop and requires resources from the test-slave
2) The external process seems to interfer with other tests since (guessing here) it is located over the browser window.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: I found a solution that simply used javas Runtime-class and run the command taskkill natively. Solves the problem of starting external processes fine. Not sure it is a recomended way. Works for me in a windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your post is, the document(word/pdf) is opening in the browser window hence you are not able to proceed with further steps. If so, you can verify the Title to make sure the document is opened in browser window and can navigate back using below snippet.

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the line

'But now I have an external application over the browser window, and it messes up for other tests.'

is that once user clicks on open button a new window opens up (Window based application) since you have mentioned PDF or Word.

You can use robot class in such cases, below code snippet will close the current active window:

```
        Robot rbt = new Robot();
        rbt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        rbt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
        rbt.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        rbt.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
```

Make sure you deal with sync issues properly so that intended window is closed instead of AUT.